# Different handleChange() functions for every single element in component? (React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I would like to know whether this is good practice or whether I should rather design this app differently. I am particulary concerned with the two 'handleChange' functions, and am wondering whether this could be simplified somehow. Other advice is also welcome, of course.

user-add.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createUser} from '../actions/index'

class UserCreate extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            inputText: 'Helluuuu'
        }
    }

    handleChangeFirstName(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({
            inputTextFirstName: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleChangeLastName(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({
            inputTextLastName: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2> Add User </h2>

                <table className="userTable">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            placeholder="Hello!"
                            value={this.state.inputTextFirstName}
                            onChange={this.handleChangeFirstName.bind(this)}/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            placeholder="Hello!"
                            value={this.state.inputTextLastName}
                            onChange={this.handleChangeLastName.bind(this)} />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>


                <button onClick={() =>this.props.createUser()}>Submit</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        user: state.activeUser
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({createUser: createUser}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserCreate);
```

Comment: Why have you initialised state `inputText`. I don't see it being consumed anywhere?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? that i put 'Helluuu' in the input text in the constructor?

Comment: oh sorry you are right, I didn't rename it into InputTextFirstName etc. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 21):

Of course you can reduce this to only one `handleChange` method and can consume as many input fields you want with that single method.

Also, I don't think you need any third party package for this.

In your render method:

```
<input 
  type="text"
  name="firstName"
  placeholder="First Name!"
  value={this.state.firstName}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
/>

<input 
  type="text"
  name="lastName"
  placeholder="Last Name!"
  value={this.state.lastName}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

**Handle Change Method**

```
handleChange(e) {
   this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
}
```

Much cleaner.

Comment: Could you explain that syntax?  It's a bit hard to google.


`{ [e.target.name] : e.target.value }`


Thanks!

Comment: @jacobra It's dynamic object key assignment. Whatever `e.target.name` is, it will become an object key.

Answer (score 10):

Beware that checkboxes work differently!

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html):

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

More concise:

```
handleInputChange({ target }) {
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.setState({ [target.name]: value });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two `handleChange` methods are fine and possibly helpful if you want to modify that data somehow in the future before submitting or so. But understandably it can be a huge hassle to create all these methods for even more form fields. Fortunately there are so-called [two-way binding helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html). As I understand they still show mixins in React's documentation, so you are probably better off with third party libraries like [`react-link-state`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-link-state):

```
import React from 'react';
import linkState from 'react-link-state';

export default MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      toggle: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" valueLink={linkState(this, 'username')} />
        <input type="password" valueLink={linkState(this, 'password')} />
        <input type="checkbox" checkedLink={linkState(this, 'toggle')}
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```